# Run specific docker container without sudo and without docker group

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sudo, sudoers

I want to run a specific docker-compose file without entering the sudo password and without assigning that user who runs the command to the docker group for security reasons.

I thought about using the `NOPASSWD` inside sudoers file and run a bash script called "bash-dockercompose-up.sh" that simply runs `docker-compose up -d`.

However, it needs the sudo command before the `docker-compose up -d` to connect to docker host.

This is my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
exampleuser        ALL=(root)       NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/bash-dockercompose-up.sh
```

Comment: Since you can specify any user ID (including root) and mount any host directory (including `/` or `/etc`) when you run a container, there are good reasons to need `sudo` to do it.  Passwordless `sudo` probably would work.  Setting this up isn't really the sort of programming-related question that's on-topic for Stack Overflow, though; consider another site like [unix.se].

Comment: @DavidMaze it's a programming related question because the bash script is being run by a nodejs exec command. It could be python or any other programming language and I would get the same output

Comment: You might look at a [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) to do this, rather than launching `docker` subprocesses.  That will require your application to have access to the Docker socket in some form, with the security implications that brings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to run it by using the python official sdk library.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/

I created a python script called "service-up.py"

service-up.py

```py
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
container = client.containers.get('id or name here')
container.start()
```

Then compile it into a binary file in order to change it's uid permissions so a non root user can run it:

```
pyinstaller service-up.py
```

move into the dist folder where file is located and run:

```
chown root:root service-up
chmod 4755 service-up
```

Comment: You can use the setuid bit on any executable, it doesn't have to be a binary. You could have just set it on a shell script.

Comment: @CalumHalpin setting suid on a python script doesn't work. I've tested it

Comment: How were you running the script? The setuid bit will only work if you set the shebang line correctly and call the script directly.